# Returning error message for my function if the argument isn't relevant

Tags: r, function

I'm practicing writing functions. I wrote a function that splits a column into different columns according to the separator (e.g., ":", "/").

I'm trying to have the function return an error message if the separator isn't relevant.

Here is the part that I am working on:

```
myfunc <- function(df, colnum = 2, into = c("a", "b", "c"), sep = ":") {

  colnum <- df[ , colnum]

  hold <- strsplit(colnum, split = sep)
  if (!grepl(sep, df)) stop()

}
```

This is returning an error message even if the separator is relevant. How can I approach this? Thank you.

Comment: You arer applying `grepl` on the entire dataset.  It should be a vector `grepl(sep, df[, colnum])`

Comment: I changed it to `if (!grepl(sep, df[ , colnum])) stop()` and now I'm getting this error message: `Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , colnum) : undefined columns selected`

Comment: also, `if` looks for length 1 and not the full length from grepl.  YOu may need to wrap with `any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OP's code, the 'colnum' is updated with the column values by assigning `colnum <- df[,colnum]`.  Instead, it can be changed to a different object name. Secondly, the `grepl` output `length` would be the same as the number of rows of the dataset and `if/else`, expects input to be of length 1 and output will be of length 1 as well.  In this case, may be, we can wrap with `any` on the condition to check if there are any `sep` that are not `:`

```
myfunc <- function(df, colnum = 2, into = c("a", "b", "c"), sep = ":") {

    colvec <- df[ , colnum] 

    hold <- strsplit(colvec, split = sep)
    if (any(!grepl(sep, df[, colnum]))) stop()
    hold


   }



myfunc(dat)
#[[1]]
#[1] "1" "2" "3"

#[[2]]
#[1] "1" "2" "3"

#[[3]]
#[1] "1" "2" "3"

#[[4]]
#[1] "1" "2" "3"

#[[5]]
#[1] "1" "2" "3"

myfunc(dat, sep=",")
#Error in myfunc(dat, sep = ",") :
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = '1:2:3', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```